Wagtail CMS in multi languages : How to diplaying 3 latest items in home page
When I create content, I have its equivalent in the languages ​​added to my site in the DB.
So how to display only the last 3 articles of a single language on the home page using "ojects.all().order_by('-date')[:3]"
def get_context(self, request):
    # Update context to include only published posts, ordered by reverse-chron
    context = super().get_context(request)
    latest_insights = Insight.objects.all().order_by('-date')[:3]
    context['latest_insights'] = latest_insights
    return context


Answer to the question regarding filtering choice lists by locale:
This is a general use FieldPanel for any single or multi choice widget that targets a translated model for the choice queryset. It limits the choices to only those from the same locale as the object being edited (i.e. if the edited page is Spanish, choices are limited to Spanish translations) - this is independent of the locale the editor uses for the admin interface.
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.forms.models import ModelChoiceIterator
from django.forms.widgets import (
    CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    RadioSelect,
    Select,
    SelectMultiple,
)
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from wagtail.admin.panels import FieldPanel


class LocalizedSelectPanel(FieldPanel):
    """
    Customised FieldPanel to filter choices based on locale of page/model being created/edited
    Usage:
    widget_class - optional, override field widget type
                 - should be CheckboxSelectMultiple, RadioSelect, Select or SelectMultiple
    typed_choice_field - set to True with Select widget forces drop down list with selector icon
    """

    def __init__(
        self, field_name, widget_class=None, typed_choice_field=False, *args, **kwargs
    ):
        if not widget_class in [
            None,
            CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            RadioSelect,
            Select,
            SelectMultiple,
        ]:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                _(
                    "widget_class should be a Django form widget class of type "
                    "CheckboxSelectMultiple, RadioSelect, Select or SelectMultiple"
                )
            )
        self.widget_class = widget_class
        self.typed_choice_field = typed_choice_field
        super().__init__(field_name, *args, **kwargs)

    def clone_kwargs(self):
        return {
            "heading": self.heading,
            "classname": self.classname,
            "help_text": self.help_text,
            "widget_class": self.widget_class,
            "typed_choice_field": self.typed_choice_field,
            "field_name": self.field_name,
        }

    class BoundPanel(FieldPanel.BoundPanel):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            if not self.panel.widget_class:
                self.form.fields[self.field_name].widget.choices = self.choice_list
            else:
                self.form.fields[self.field_name].widget = self.panel.widget_class(
                    choices=self.choice_list
                )
            if self.panel.typed_choice_field:
                self.form.fields[
                    self.field_name
                ].__class__.__name__ = "typed_choice_field"
            pass

        @property
        def choice_list(self):
            self.form.fields[self.field_name].queryset = self.form.fields[
                self.field_name
            ].queryset.filter(locale_id=self.instance.locale_id)
            return ModelChoiceIterator(self.form.fields[self.field_name])

Example use:
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField(
        "blog.BlogCategory",
        verbose_name=_("Blog Categories"),
        related_name="categories",
    )
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
         ....
         LocalizedSelectPanel('categories', CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    ]


It'll show the translated snippets in the language of the object being edited. If you're editing an English page, you get the English translations, if you're editing a Spanish, you get the Spanish translations etc..

Hi, I used your recipe which consists of filtering the sippets models with the locale_id=active_lang.id and it works wonderfully!
Thanks a lot.
Now my problem is how to apply the same principle on my personalized main menu translated into several languages?
Menu links only point to pages in the main language of the site.

You need to localize the menu item - menu_item.localized.url. Make sure you do have translations if you use that, if a translation is missing, you'll just get menu_item.url in the original language. Otherwise make a template tag that check for the translation and handles the case when it is missing (hide the link for example).

Ok thanks i found it

You can use Locale to filter the queryset. Get the active language, use the id of the active locale:
from wagtail.models import Locale
active_lang = Locale.get_active()
latest_insights = Insight.objects.filter(locale_id=active_lang.id).order_by('-date')[:3]


Oh thank you very much! that solves my problem.
I have the same problem with translatable snippets, the equivalents in other languages ​​are displayed at the same time!
Can you enlighten me on how to go about it please?

That works exactly the same way for filtering: YourModel.Insight.objects.filter(locale_id=active_lang.id). If you are referring to choice fields that are linked to multi-lingual snippets, this needs a custom fieldpanel to filter the choice queryset. I can post an example of that here if you need.

Yes brother i nedd it please

For example, here is my translatable snippet, but unfortunately all its equivalents in other languages ​​are displayed at the same time on the site, whereas I only want that of the current language of the site to be displayed.
translatable snippet

I've added an answer above with the code for a FieldPanel that filters the locales to match the locale of the page/model being edited.

ellipses? Did you copy the example code exactly as I wrote it? the .... is just there to mean your other field panels for your page model, I didn't mean for you to actually use that in your code....
